# How to get the id of a row and display in materialize modal in php

Tags: php, materialize

I'm having problem of getting the id of a row. All I want is to update the data row using materialize CSS modal but I can't get the `id` of that row. I tried this code (it's inside the display loop)

```
 <a class="waves-effect waves-light modal-trigger" href="#modal1 ? id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone please help me. I'm beginner in materialize.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with materialize. You are mixing up html, JS and PHP.

Comment: Uhhmm.. Maybe. But how can i get the id of a row? I'm using materialize modal.